# Extracting value from string that could change ordering

Tags: python-3.x

I have a substring returned from an API call:

```
in_string="JID=1234; path=/demand; HttpOnly; Secure, OPU=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00 GMT; path=/Demand; secure, OA_OS=$66+Y=; expires=Tue, 04-Mar-1990 15:55:22 GMT; path=/; secure"
```

I need a reliable way to always extract the "1234" my current solution doesn't seem elegant and wont handle if the string ever changes order:

```
in_string.split(';')[0].replace('JID=','')
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Comment: You could just search through the String to find JID, drop the character after that (the =), then take while the characters are digits. This is quite broad though.

Comment: @ck3mp did the answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using regex?

```
import re

in_string="JID=1234; path=/demand; HttpOnly; Secure, OPU=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00 GMT; path=/Demand; secure, OA_OS=$66+Y=; expires=Tue, 04-Mar-1990 15:55:22 GMT; path=/; secure"

JID_number_pattern = re.compile(r'JID=\d{1,}')

JID_number = re.search(JID_number_pattern,in_string)
if JID_number:
   print (JID_number.group(0).replace('JID=',''))
   # output
   1234
```